# can common document file formats be opened by an external application?

Tags: android

I have a list of file URLs (pdf, doc, xls). I can open them with external applications. But what if a device doesn't have an XLS-viewer?

How to check if xls can be opened *before* downloading the file?

Comment: I think it is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663818/how-do-i-display-a-list-of-all-mime-types-supported-by-a-given-android-device.

Comment: I think that the Apache-POI libraries can open standard doc and xls files. Not sure if they can also open docx and xlsx. For PDF files, there are free libraries to open them.

Comment: @KlingKlang, thanks. I open these files by external applications. I decided to try opening a file and go to PlayMarket if it can't be opened.